# How may I put the last post summary of a blog inside of the main page of another blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have two blogs. One personal and other professional. I do not want my clients to see my personal stuff inside my professional blog, but I want the last professional post two be viewed in my personal blog. If the reader clicks on the title, he is redirected to the professional blog.

How do I do that? Is that even possible?

---

Something like the kind of link that wordpress consider as requesting the last post, like if it was `site.com/wp/lastpost-non-themed` for example...

Answer (score 0):

Should be no problem if you know how to program. :)

You can create a page that displays only the post summary and `include()` it at the other page.

Looping something like this should do it:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
```

Comment: I need something like the kind of link that wordpress consider as requesting the last post, like if it was site.com/wp/lastpost-non-themed for example... then I would put that into include()